# High Chart line single data set but multiple color, not gradient color

Tags: javascript, colors, highcharts

Using latest High Chart, I want to have a single line with red color when the line is below some y-value and green otherwise (See picture http://oi60.tinypic.com/1t0ftu.jpg). Currently this is achieved by concatenating green and red lines (ie. 2 data sets) like this:

```
    series: [{
        color: 'red',
        data: [{x:1,y:3}
               , {x:2, y:2}]

    },
    {
        color: 'green',
        data: [{x:2, y:2}, {x:3, y:1}]

    }]
```

However, this introduces issues and I have to use 1 data set (ie. single series).
Can someone show me how to achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

- use [`threshold`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.threshold) option
- use multicolor series [plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/33/Multicolor%20series)